# Search for passwords in Jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I've a Jupiter notebook server being used by over 50 users.

Is there a solution out there that searches for secrets/passwords across all the notebooks? It's a challenge in terms of security, when a some users leave their secrets/passwords in their scripts exposed to other group of users.

Comment: What have you tried? maybe base on https://github.com/Yelp/detect-secrets

Comment: Thanks. That looks promising. I was trying with a bespoke bash script, but it was not efficient enough.